# Query for latest data from updated date timestamp

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

I just want to get the latest record from my table based on my updated timstamp data, because I want to run this query in my crontab. How can I always get the latest updated data from my query? This is my query:

```
select 
    x.updated as updated,
    x.data_a->>'custom1' as mch_group,
    x.data_a->>'custom2' as mch_name,
    x.data_a->>'custom3' as mch_id,
    x.data_a->'simAuxFieldsDTO'->>'custom4' as terminal_id,
    x.data_a->>'msisdn' as msisdn, 
    x.data_a->>'simId' as sim_id,
    x.data_a->>'acctName' as acct_name, 
    x.data_a->>'activationDate' as activation_date,
    x.data_a->>'inSession' as in_session, 
    x.data_a->>'sessionType' as session_type,
    x.data_a->>'statusNameDisplay' as status_name_display, 
    x.data_a->>'monthToDateDataUsageMB' as month_todate_data_usage, 
    x.data_a->>'linePayStatus' as line_pay_status, 
    x.data_a->>'iccid' as iccid, 
    x.data_a->>'monthToDateSmsUsage' as month_todate_sms_usage, 
    x.data_a->>'monthToDateVoiceUsage' as month_todate_voice_usage, 
    x.data_a->>'overageLimitReached' as overage_limit_reached, 
    x.data_a->>'termStartDate' as term_startdate, 
    x.data_a->>'termEndDate' as term_enddate, 
    x.data_a->>'migratedSim' as migrated_sim 
 from (
   select jsonb_array_elements(a.data_a) as data_a, a.updated as updated 
   from (
     select updated, json_data -> 'data' as data_a 
     from tcash_edc_json 
     where updated > TO_TIMESTAMP('2018-09-21 03:02:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS')
    )a
) x;
```

Answer (score 1):

try replacing the where conditions with order by and limit:
instead of this:

```
where updated > TO_TIMESTAMP('2018-09-21 03:02:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS')
```

this:

```
order by updated desc limit 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to get max(updated) and then do the select where updated = max (updated)